# R-MICE error imputing unordered variable with more than 50 categories

Tags: r, r-mice

I'm trying to impute a set of variables that are categorical (unordered). These variables are part of a large dataset and have approximately 75 categories. The relevant line of code is below and the error is.

> Error in augment(y, ry, x, wy) :    Maximum number of categories (50)
> exceeded

Line that produces error:

```
miceouts4 <- mice(data = imp_sc3a, m = 3, method="polyreg", print = TRUE,
              predictorMatrix = predictorMatrix, blocks=imputedVars)
```

Is there a way to set the number of categories or overwrite the maximum of 50 categories? I can do this imputation without much pain in SAS but R-MICE imputations of continuous variables are far faster so I would like to stick with R in doing a series of imputations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-John